# groff arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, groff

Is it possible to perform arithmetic using groff?
Say I want to calculate what page is the current one, and I currently am on page 2.
I can get the next page's number by using:

```
.PP
Next page is number \n[.pn]
```

Which will compile as `Next page is number 3`.

How can I perform arithmetic to render instead:

```
.PP
Current page is ((\n[.pn]-1))
```

into `Current page is 2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current page number is `\n%` .

To interpolate the result of an arithmetic expression, I think you'll need to put it in a number register first.

Here's a macro (not exhaustively tested) that takes an expression as its argument, assigns the result to a (presumably unused) register named `__`, then interpolates the contents of the register.

```
Current page is \n%.
.br
.\" EI - eval and interpolate
.\" $1 is an expression to evaluate
.\" $2 (optional) is a string to append to the interpolated expression,
.\"    without any intervening whitespace
.de EI
.nr __ \\$1
\&\\n(__\\$2
..
.nr x 4
4 times 3 minus 5 is
'EI (\nx*3-5)
\&.
.br
Here there's no space before the period:
'EI (\nx*3-5) .
.br
```

After running through nroff:

```
Current page is 1.
4 times 3 minus 5 is 7 .
Here there's no space before the period: 7.
```

This seems like such a common thing to do that there may be a macro like it already in the standard macro packages, but I don't know.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have been looking in the man page and different tutorials on groff, troff, several macro packages, and none seem to provide a simple solution. I'll definitely use your solution in a project now. It also taught me a lot about arguments in groff which isn't very clear for a beginner. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `groff` can perform arithmetic.  This is documented in the full groff manual, which is available online or in GNU Info format (use `info groff`, or `pinfo groff` to see the full manual)....as with many GNU programs, the man page is just a quick reference, full docs are in Info format.

From https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Expressions.html

> gtroff has most arithmetic operators common to other languages:
>
> - Arithmetic: ‘+’ (addition), ‘-’ (subtraction), ‘/’ (division), ‘*’
>     (multiplication), ‘%’ (modulo).
>
> gtroff only provides integer
>   arithmetic. The internal type used for computing results is ‘int’,
>   which is usually a 32-bit signed integer.
>
> - Comparison: ‘<’ (less than), ‘>’ (greater than), ‘<=’ (less than or
>     equal), ‘>=’ (greater than or equal), ‘=’ (equal), ‘==’ (the same as
>     ‘=’).
> - Logical: ‘&’ (logical and), ‘:’ (logical or).
> - Unary operators: ‘-’ (negating, i.e. changing the sign), ‘+’ (just for completeness;
>     does nothing in expressions), ‘!’ (logical not; this works only within
>     if and while requests). See below for the use of unary operators in
>     motion requests.
>
> The logical not operator, as described above, works
>   only within if and while requests. Furthermore, it may appear only at
>   the beginning of an expression, and negates the entire expression.
>
> Attempting to insert the ‘!’ operator within the expression results in
>   a ‘numeric expression expected’ warning. This maintains compatibility
>   with old versions of troff.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> .nr X 1
> .nr Y 0
> .\" This does not work as expected
> .if (\n[X])&(!\n[Y]) .nop X only
> .
> .\" Use this construct instead
> .if (\n[X]=1)&(\n[Y]=0) .nop X only
> ```

---

BTW, `info` is the standard GNU Info document viewer.   [pinfo](https://github.com/baszoetekouw/pinfo) is an alternative viewer that provides a more "browser-like" UI, similar to a text web browser like `lynx`.  I personally can't stand `info` and use `pinfo` instead.   It's available pre-packaged for most distros and source code is available in the pinfo link above.